# Lambda Map Behavior in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, lambda

I came across some codes while looking at someone else's solution on LeetCode:

```
def findLeaves(self, root):
    if not root: return []
    kids = map(self.findLeaves, (root.left, root.right))
    return map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *kids) + [[root.val]]
```

I found that it only works on Python 2 but not 3, so I did the following debugging:

Python 2:

```
a = [[],[]]
b = map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *a) + [[4]]
c = map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *a) + [[5]]
d = map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *[b,c]) + [[2]]
e = [[3]]
f = map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *[d,e]) + [[1]]
print f
```

Python 3:

```
a = [[],[]]
b = list(map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *a)) + [[4]]
c = list(map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *a)) + [[5]]
d = list(map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *[b,c])) + [[2]]
e = [[3]]
f = list(map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *[d,e])) + [[1]]
print(f)
```

The above code return `[[4, 5, 3], [2], [1]]` in Python 2 (which is correct) and `[[4, 5, 3], [1]]` in Python 3 (which is wrong).

`*[d,e]` is `[[4,5], [2]] [[3]]`, in Python 2, when processing `[[2]]` it will auto assign `None` to r in the lambda expression. But in Python 3, it will skip the record.

I also found that in Python 2, if I changed `f` to `list(map(lambda l, r: (l or []) + (r or []), *itertools.zip_longest(d,e))) + [[1]]`, it will work. However, it will mess up the case for b and c.

Can anyone explain what is the right way to fix the code? Also, the way I debug is very dumb (I always use print), any better way to debug codes? I am new to Python and using the Jupyter notebook to run my codes.

Comment: This code does not run in Python3. Furthermore, even after fixing the print, map is an iterator in Python3 and cannot be concatenated to a list. What did you run exactly?

Comment: That's a very elaborate way to assign `[[4]]` to `b` and `[[5]]` to `c`...

Comment: The link that you provide doesn't work for others. Please give a [mcve] which doesn't depend on linked code.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Updated the question, sorry for the late response

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry for the bad question format, I updated the question.

Comment: Of `a, b, c, d, e, f` -- which is the *first* in which you see a difference between Python 2 and Python 3? I suspect that your example is not minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` in python 3 doesn't pad with `None`, you'll need to do that yourself. You might want to use `zip_longest` and maybe starmap.

[Python 2 docs for map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

> map(function, iterable, ...) Apply function to every item of iterable
>   and return a list of the results. If additional iterable arguments are
>   passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the
>   items from all iterables in parallel. If one iterable is shorter than
>   another it is assumed to be extended with None items. If function is
>   None, the identity function is assumed; if there are multiple
>   arguments, map() returns a list consisting of tuples containing the
>   corresponding items from all iterables (a kind of transpose
>   operation). The iterable arguments may be a sequence or any iterable
>   object; the result is always a list.

[Python 3 docs for map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable,
>   yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed,
>   function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items
>   from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator
>   stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. For cases where the
>   function inputs are already arranged into argument tuples, see
>   itertools.starmap().